# \widthof{} command in \FPeval

Tags: fp

Could someone please tell me how I can use the `\widthof{}` command from the `calc` package within `\FPeval` from the `fp` package?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fp}
\begin{document}
\FPeval\result{(2.5-\widthof{13})/2}
\end{document}
```

Even with `\csname` and `\value`, or `\arabic`, it still results in an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\widthof` of package `calc` is only supported inside `\setlength` and `\addtolength`. Also package `fp` does not deal with dimensions, but real numbers. `\strip@pt` extracts the number of a length/dimen register and removes the unit `pt`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fp}
\newdimen\tempdimen
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\tempdimen}{\widthof{13}}
\FPeval\result{(2.5-\strip@pt\tempdimen)/2}
\makeatother
\typeout{Result: \result}
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
Result: -3.750015000000000000
```

Comment: Use `\settowidth`?

Comment: @JosephWright `\settowidth{\tempdimen}{13}` is shorter and does not depend on package `calc`; therefore it is the better choice. However, it does not show, how `\widthof` can be used with the `fp` package. ;-)

Comment: How would you write a command to do this? So far I have `\newcommand{\test}[1]{\makeatletter\setlength{\tempdimen}{\widthof{#1}}\FPeval\resultaP(2.5-\strip@pt\tempdimen)/2}\makeatother}`, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user111 `\strip@pt` contains `@`, which needs the category code letter.  The category codes are used, when TeX tokenizes the input bytes, that means definition time here, not execution time of the defined macro. `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` must go outside the definition: `\makeatletter\newcommand*{\test}[1]{\settowidth{\tempdimen}{#1}\FPeval\resultaP(2.5-\strip@pt\tempdimen)/2}}\maketother`.

Comment: BTW, there is a followup [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/310850/16967) with a good answer by cfr.