# \FPeval not working in new command

Tags: fp

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fp}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{
\makeatletter
\setlength{\tempdimen}{\widthof{#1}}
\FPeval\‌​resultaP(70-\strip@pt\tempdimen)/2}
\makeatother}
\begin{document}
\test{5}
\end{document}
```

The command does not work when called in the document. However, if its contents are typed manually, it seems to work. Could someone please help?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201348/21930

Comment: @Manuel Yes, but that is not the only problem here!

Comment: How are you typing it manually? It doesn't work for me (and I wouldn't expect it to, either).

Comment: What is `\strip@pt`?

Comment: @Bernard It strips the `pt` from a dimension: `\newlength\tempdimen
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \setlength\tempdimen{#1}%
  \strip@pt\tempdimen
}
` Then `\test{5pt}` returns `5`.

Comment: Related: [`\widthof` command in `\FPeval`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/310823/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [the question Manuel linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201348/21930), the first problem is that you cannot use `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` in the definition of a macro.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}[1]{
\setlength{\tempdimen}{\widthof{#1}}
\FPeval\‌​resultaP(70-\strip@pt\tempdimen)/2}
}
\makeatother
```

In addition, you cannot `\setlength` a length without creating it first.

```
\makeatletter
\newlength\tempdimen
\newcommand{\test}[1]{
  \setlength{\tempdimen}{\widthof{#1}}
  \FPeval\‌​resultaP(70-\strip@pt\tempdimen)/2}
}
\makeatother
```

If we are working from your code, we also need to eliminate the strange invisible characters.

```
\makeatletter
\newlength\tempdimen
\newcommand{\test}[1]{
  \setlength{\tempdimen}{\widthof{#1}}
  \FPeval\resultaP{(70-\strip@pt\tempdimen)/2}
  \FPprint‌\resultaP
}
\makeatother
```

Then it works without issue. (`\FPprint\resultaP` added for demonstration purposes.)

However, this code will not necessarily give you the results you want. For example,

```
Here is an example: \test{5}.

Here is another: \test{5}--\test{7809}.
```

produces

[image: spurious spaces]

because the definition of the macro tells TeX to insert spaces at various points - quite a lot of them, in fact.

To avoid this, we need

```
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \setlength{\tempdimen}{\widthof{#1}}%
  \FPeval\resultaP{(70-\strip@pt\tempdimen)/2}%
  \FPprint‌\resultaP
}
```

which gives the expected result

[image: expected result]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fp}
\makeatletter
\newlength\tempdimen
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \setlength{\tempdimen}{\widthof{#1}}%
  \FPeval\resultaP{(70-\strip@pt\tempdimen)/2}%
  \FPprint‌\resultaP
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Here is an example: \test{5}.

Here is another: \test{5}--\test{7809}.
\end{document}
```

As [Heiko Oberdiek points out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310850/fpeval-not-working-in-new-command/310856?noredirect=1#comment755470_310856), for the minimal example, at least, `\widthof` is not required and `calc` need not be used. (In fact, I'd never heard of `\widthof` and have always used `\settowidth` so tested with that originally.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\makeatletter
\newlength\tempdimen
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \settowidth\tempdimen{#1}%
  \FPeval\resultaP{(70-\strip@pt\tempdimen)/2}%
  \FPprint‌\resultaP
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Here is an example: \test{5}.

Here is another: \test{5}--\test{7809}.
\end{document}
```

There are easier packages to use than `fp` by now, I think. Or, at least, better documented ones.

Comment: Very comprehensive +1. A last step, package `calc` with `\widthof` is not really needed here, the setting of `\tempdimen` can be simplified by `\settowidth`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I thought maybe that was needed for other 'big picture' reasons. I noticed that you answered a question explicitly about using `\widthof` with `fp`. But if you think it is worth adding that, I can do so. I actually tested with `\settowidth` because I'd never come across `\widthof` before and always find `fp` confusing enough to begin with. (I think just the TODO status of the documentation ...)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I've added your suggested version. Is there an advantage to `\widthof`? I've never come across it before, but perhaps I've just led a sheltered life ;).

Comment: The advantage of `\widthof` (and `\heightof`, `\depthof`, `\totalheightof`) is that these commands can be used inside `calc` expressions of `\addtolength` and `\setlength`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Oh, OK. I see that. I just wondered if there was anything else. Thanks a lot!